# Twilio TCDevice initialization crash

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, twilio

I'm using twilio iOS version 'TwilioSDK', '~>1.2.9’ for calling to a mobile number. Below code is to initialize TCDevice, its crashing at the exact line after 2sec

```
class PhoneVC: UIViewController, TCDeviceDelegate, TCConnectionDelegate {

    var device:TCDevice?
    var connection:TCConnection?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
        // just assume i have token already
       device = TCDevice.init(capabilityToken: token, delegate: self)
    }
}
```

and the crash is showing here [image]

not able to find the exact issue, can u guys help.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check and make sure the class you are initializing it in adopts and implements Twilio's delegate protocols. You are setting the delegate to `self`, so Twilio could be trying to call a delegate method that doesn't exist. See [this](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/client/ios#explore-the-server-starter-application) example.

For future reference, please post the full stack trace or at least the code one frame higher. The assembly code is not super helpful.

Comment: even if i set delegate to nil. same result.

Comment: It probably will not work without the delegate set up correctly. The delegate lets Twilio tell your application when there is new information. If that doesn't fix it you'll need to post some more information (stack trace, class declaration).

Comment: In viewDidLoad you are setting the TCDevice to a local variable that is destroyed after leaving the function. Instead of `let device = ...` it should be `device = ...` (or `self.device = ...` to be explicit)

Comment: did that. i think problem is i have temasys, aws and twilio in my pod. each having their own ssl thing. i think ssl is conflicting. any ideas how to deal with it

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem. Did you check that all of the delegate functions in the example I posted above are implemented?

Comment: yes i did. If i create a new project and implement all the twilio. it is working. Its not working in my existing project

Comment: Hmm. Next thing I would try is Product->Clean and re-run `pod install`

Comment: did that and also i tried to remove the twilio pod and implemented manually same error. Is there any way to mention the path of the ssl?

Comment: You'll need to post more detail about the error. I'm not sure what you mean by SSL in this context.